# Issue with onClick not working for FCM messages that have been unchecked for a long time (within 6 hours)

Tags: reactjs, onclick, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my React project, I use Firebase 9 to fetch FCM messages from the server, and when I click on a message, a new window opens with the URL passed from the server.

Click events work on FCM messages as soon as they are received, but not on messages that have been unread for more than three minutes.

This does not happen in the local environment, only in the deployment environment.

Has anyone experienced or resolved this issue?

My test environment looks like this.

1. Macbook pro
2. Chrome browser
3. Google Chrome Helper( Alerts )